# "Error accessing file" While uploading app. Its trying to access old directory

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, itmstransporter

I got an error while uploading my app to iTunes Connect through Xcode. Below attached image I have copied someone's image but I am also facing the exact issue.

Path: `/Users/User/.itmstransporter/obr`

My path: `/Users/mysivana/.itmstransporter/obr`

I have removed "mysivana" home directory a while ago. Now I am trying to upload the old app and it's trying to access the old directory. I am unable to resolve this issue for the past 15 days.

Please help out, thanks in advance.

image URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvrez.png

Comment: Try to use the Application Loader app.

Comment: Same error message it showing in Application loader too